# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment (Real Estate price prediction project)

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am working on this real Estate price prediction project I found online. But I Keep getting this error, and don't know how to fix it. 
Please help me out! Thanks

```
def predict_price(location, sqft, bath, bhk): 
    loc_index = np.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]
    x = np.zeros(len(x.columns))
    x[0] = sqft
    x[1] = bath
    x[2] = bhk
    if loc_index >=0: 
        x[loc_index] = 1

    return lr_clf.predict(x)[0]
predict_price('1st Phase JP Nagar',1000, 2, 2)
```

Comment: In the first line of the function, what is the value of `x`?

Comment: Are you talking about this ? x = df12.drop('price', axis='columns')
x.head()

Comment: Here: `loc_index = np.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]` Where does `x` come from? Is it a global variable?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCiRv94GMEc  @13.15. Im new to this LOOL i'm not sure if it's a global variable .

Answer (score 1):

According to the video you sent in the comment, you typed an `x` instead of an `X` in the first line of the code. Try:

```
def predict_price(location, sqft, bath, bhk): 
    loc_index = np.where(X.columns==location)[0][0]
    x = np.zeros(len(x.columns))
    x[0] = sqft
    x[1] = bath
    x[2] = bhk
    if loc_index >=0: 
        x[loc_index] = 1

    return lr_clf.predict(x)[0]
predict_price('1st Phase JP Nagar',1000, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

def predict_price(location,sqft,bath,bhk):
global x
loc_index = np.where(x.columns==location)[0][0]

```
x = np.zeros(len(x.columns))
x[0] = sqft
x[1] = bath
x[2] = bhk
if loc_index >= 0:
    x[loc_index] = 1
    
return lr_clf.predict([x])[0]
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly and have a brief explanation?